# Materializecss & vue3: how to use sass @extend to color text?

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I've installed materializecss in my Vue 3.0 project using npm.
It's imported in my main.js:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to use @extend to color text, like this:

```
<style lang="scss">
  .a {
      @extend .grey-text, .text-lighten-3;
  }
</style>
```

I'm getting an error:

```
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .grey-text !optional" to avoid this error.
```

If I use "!optional", the rule isn't applied.
Is it possible to use materializecss sass extends in Vue3? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to import/initialize the Sass partial containing the CSS rule (selector) to be extended.

Sass in Vue component files is scoped and does not see any code from outside that file (even if you do not use the `scoped` keyword in the style tag). This is also how `dart-sass` works by default.

Presuming Materialize is installed as a node_module, and that the typography partial is where your extended class is located, you @use it like this:

```
@use 'materialize-css/sass/components/_typography' as *;

a {
  @extend .grey-text, .text-lighten-3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still the same error, updated with percentages

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the issue, after a second thought I have updated the answer. You don't need the %, the dots should work. What's missing is the extensible class which you need to import with @use first.

Comment: Proof of a similar concept here, where we @use variables from a node package in a Vue component: https://github.com/ahansson/hgrid-css-vue-vite/blob/master/src/components/Counter.vue

Comment: The path is actually @use 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss' as *; but the answer was correct thx!! I have one question more: if I used the other scss preprocessor available with vue cli (node sass or smt), would that solve the problem without using @use?

Comment: Ok, will update the answer. with the right path But be careful, if you @use materialise.scss you import the complete framework into your component. Try instead to find the particular file where your extensible class is located to avoid getting a full duplicate of Materialize in every component. Node-sass is deprecated by now, should not be used. Before sass-dart everything in Sass was probably global, they isolated modules with `@use` and other techniques to allow namespacing. More onerous but also much more solid in big projects.

Comment: if I @use the "more right" file, I got compilation errors which might be a topic for whole another thread. I imported the above mentioned one in my App.vue and seems like it's available everywhere. Not sure if it's a best practice, but works.